# iOS9 in-app purchase error code changed for user cancellation?

Tags: ios8, in-app-purchase, ios9

On iOS8, in my app (which is working fine), if the user is not logged in with their Apple Id, and they attempt an in-app purchase, they get the following Apple alert:

[image]

Now, if the user presses "Cancel",in the code, we get an error **code 2** with the **SKPaymentTransaction**. This has the enum code **SKErrorPaymentCancelled**

On iOS9, in the same situation, we now get error code 0,

> Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store}

This has enum code SKErrorUnknown, which doesn't seem useful.

Anyone else run into this? The difficult here is in my app UI. If I get an error code, SKErrorPaymentCancelled, I don't present any info to the user as it is clear that the user has explicitly done a cancellation.

With **SKErrorUnknown**, I can't tell what has gone on, so I present an error alert to the user. Which, if they have explicitly cancelled, is just annoying. Thoughts?

Comment: I have just submitted a bug report on this to Apple.

Comment: i am having the same issue... if no user is logged in i will get this error

Answer (score 0):

May be :

1. Your app is enabled only for other location, test user was localized for other - and with this setup does not work. You should enabled the app for USA and created a test user localized in USA and it seems to work (no code change at all). And I think that proves that the code is ok, just the apple sandbox has some problems with non USA test users.
2. And don't login from settings. When this login form comes from your app, try it.